# $ \sum_{a \mid n} \Bigl( f(a) \sum_{b \mid \frac{n}{a}} g(b) \Bigr) = \sum_{a \mid n} \Bigl( g(a) \sum_{b \mid \frac{n}{a}} f(b) \Bigr) $

Tags: summation, divisibility

Is the following equation true?

$$
\sum_{a \mid n} \Bigl( f(a) \sum_{b \mid \frac{n}{a}} g(b) \Bigr) =
\sum_{a \mid n} \Bigl( g(a) \sum_{b \mid \frac{n}{a}} f(b) \Bigr)
$$

If this equation is true, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: both sides are equal to $\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{a,b,c\\abc=n}}f(a)g(b)$.

Answer (score 0):

We can conveniently prove this identity between *[arithmetical functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function)* $f$ and $g$ using the *[Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution)*
\begin{align*}
(f\ast g)(n)=\sum_{d|n}f(d)g\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)
\end{align*}
The Dirichlet convolution is commutative $f\ast g=g\ast f$ and associative  $f\ast(g\ast h)=(f\ast g)\ast h$. We also use the constant function  $\zeta$ which is defined as
\begin{align*}
\zeta(n)=1\qquad\qquad n\geq 1
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{a|n}f(a)\sum_{b|\frac{n}{a}}g(b)}&=\sum_{a|n}f(a)\sum_{b|\frac{n}{a}}g(b)\zeta\left(\frac{\frac{n}{a}}{b}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{a|n}f(a)\left(g\ast\zeta\right)\left(\frac{n}{a}\right)\\
> &=\left(f\ast\left(g\ast\zeta\right)\right)(n)\\
> &=\left(\left(g \ast\zeta\right)\ast f\right)(n)\\
> &=\left(g \ast\left(\zeta\ast f\right)\right)(n)\\
> &=\left(g \ast\left(f\ast \zeta\right)\right)(n)\\
> &=\sum_{a|n}g(a)\left(f\ast \zeta\right)\left(\frac{n}{a}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{a|n}g(a)\sum_{b|\frac{n}{a}}f(b)\zeta\left(\frac{\frac{n}{a}}{b}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{a|n}g(a)\sum_{b|\frac{n}{a}}f(b)}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.